# How to deal with version issues in android 1.6 to 2.x

Tags: android, json

I built a JSON consumer in android for 1.6 (thought it was good practice to build on the oldest version for max support). I was able to successfully retrieve the json under 1.5-1.6. However I just threw the app on my droid (2.x) and now I receive "org.json.jsonexception: expected literal value at character ....". Why the difference in versions? How can I deal with this?

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a method to convert the InputStream to a string representation of the JSON. I needed to adjust the substring from (intial, length()-1) to (initial, length()-2) to get it to work in both 1.5 and 2.x.  Thanks for the help.

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {  
   /* 
    * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine() 
    * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader returns null which means 
    * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder 
    * and returned as String. 
    */  
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  

    String line = null;  
    try {  
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {  
            sb.append(line + "\n");  
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } finally {  
        try {  
            is.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }
    // API is defective and does not return correct json response.
    // Reformat string response to confirm to expected json response
    // return sb.toString();
    return  "{\"Results\":" + sb.substring(11, sb.length()-2) + "}\n" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get it working with that library, try GSON which is great

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. In my case, it turned out that the JSON lib was confused because the `JSON` returned had the quotes **(")** escaped. This apparently confused it about the length of the string, and caused the exception.